# How to pass php value from current page into popup page (External)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem with my work. There is a repetition for button and value based on database. I want to get selected value from current page into a pop up page when the selected button were clicked every repetition. the pop up page is the external page PHP.

Here my whole code

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <!-- popup -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script>
    $("a#selector").live("click", function(){
        $(".overlayInner").load("callinboundcall.php",
           // the following is the callback   
          function(){$(".overlayOuter").fadeIn(100); })
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .overlayOuter{
        background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        opacity:0.99;
        display:none;
        height:100%;
        left:0;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        z-index:100001;
     }


    .overlayInner{

        position:absolute;
        background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        border: 1px solid grey;
        opacity: 1.7;
        overflow:scroll;
        top:7%;/*or whatever*/
        left:27%; /*or whatever*/
        width:45%;
        height:75%;
        z-index:100001;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php>
    $call = pg_query("SELECT InputDate,CallId,AgentName,Reviewer,SalamPembuka,KonfirmasiNamaCust,VerifikasiData,KemampuanBertanya,ProductKnowledge,Solusi,AlternativeSolusi ,SistemPelaporan,Empati,Responsif,RamahSopan,PercayaDiri,HoldCall,OfferHelp,Penutup,GrandTotal FROM Call WHERE InputDate >= '$start' AND InputDate <= '$end'");
        while($result=pg_fetch_row($call))
            {

                 echo
                "
                <tr>
                <td  align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[0]</td>
                <td align=\"center\"  class=\"form\">$result[1]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[2]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[3]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[4]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[5]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[6]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[7]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[8]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[9]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[10]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[11]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[12]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[13]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[14]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[15]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[16]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[17]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[18]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[19]</td>
                <td  class=\"form\" width=\"2%\"><a id=\"selector\"  href=\"#\" ><img  width=\"120%\" height=\"130%\" src=\"../img/view.png\"/></a></td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\" width=\"2%\"><img  width=\"90%\" height=\"90%\" src=\"../img/edit.png\" onclick=\"myDeleteFunction()\"/></td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\" width=\"2%\"><input onclick=\"deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)\" type=\"image\" src=\"../img/delete.png\" alt=\"Submit\" width=\"110%\" height=\"110%\"></td>

                </tr>\n
                ";

            }
<?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The button is in `<a id="selector">`.

The output 
[image]

Popup when first row button clicked
[image]

The value `$result[1]` would be appear at the top corner popup.The row is the result of repetition.
What am i supposed to do? Thankyou in Advanced. if you don't understand, let me know. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass a variable, probably using a query string parameter, to the `callinboundcall.php` file. You'll probably want to do something like:

```
<script>
$("a.selector").live("click", function(){
    $(".overlayInner").load(this.href,
       // the following is the callback   
      function(){$(".overlayOuter").fadeIn(100);
   });
   return false;
});
</script>
```

A few points:

1. You can't have multiple elements on an HTML page with the same `id` attribute. Uses HTML `class` attribute instead.
2. If you're attaching a handler to links which will load data, it's nice to load the link's `href` rather than some arbitrary URL
3. You should add a column to your database with and ID number, so you can refer to your rows with a unique numeric ID.

Doing this will allow you to pass an ID of a row number to `callinboundcall.php` which you will read using `$_GET['id']`, or whatever *query string parameters* you passed in the AJAX call to `callinboundcall.php`

Given that you said `CallID` is a unique ID, here's a modified version of your PHP:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <!-- popup -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script>
    $("a.selector").live("click", function(){
        $(".overlayInner").load(this.href,
           // the following is the callback   
          function(){$(".overlayOuter").fadeIn(100);
        });
        return false;
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .overlayOuter{
        background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        opacity:0.99;
        display:none;
        height:100%;
        left:0;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        z-index:100001;
     }


    .overlayInner{

        position:absolute;
        background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        border: 1px solid grey;
        opacity: 1.7;
        overflow:scroll;
        top:7%;/*or whatever*/
        left:27%; /*or whatever*/
        width:45%;
        height:75%;
        z-index:100001;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php>
    $call = pg_query("SELECT InputDate,CallId,AgentName,Reviewer,SalamPembuka,KonfirmasiNamaCust,VerifikasiData,KemampuanBertanya,ProductKnowledge,Solusi,AlternativeSolusi ,SistemPelaporan,Empati,Responsif,RamahSopan,PercayaDiri,HoldCall,OfferHelp,Penutup,GrandTotal FROM Call WHERE InputDate >= '$start' AND InputDate <= '$end'");
        $index = 0;
        while($result=pg_fetch_row($call))
            {

                 echo
                "
                <tr>
                <td  align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[0]</td>
                <td align=\"center\"  class=\"form\">$result[1]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[2]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[3]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[4]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[5]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[6]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[7]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[8]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[9]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[10]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[11]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[12]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[13]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[14]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[15]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[16]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[17]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[18]</td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\">$result[19]</td>
                <td  class=\"form\" width=\"2%\"><a class=\"selector\"  href=\"callinboundcall.php?id={$result[1]}\" ><img  width=\"120%\" height=\"130%\" src=\"../img/view.png\"/></a></td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\" width=\"2%\"><img  width=\"90%\" height=\"90%\" src=\"../img/edit.png\" onclick=\"myDeleteFunction()\"/></td>
                <td align=\"center\" class=\"form\" width=\"2%\"><input onclick=\"deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)\" type=\"image\" src=\"../img/delete.png\" alt=\"Submit\" width=\"110%\" height=\"110%\"></td>

                </tr>\n
                ";
                $index++;
            }
<?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's what I did:

- The jQuery handler now looks for links by `class` and not `id`
- The jQuery handler now opens the `href` of the links
- I added an `$index` counter to know which row number each link should fetch. *This should be replaced with a unique identifier for each row instead*, that will be much better
- The links themselves now link to `callinboundcall.php?index=$index`

  - Linking to `callinboundcall.php?index=$row['id']` would be better, if you had a unique ID column.

Now, `callinboundcall.php` should perform a database query to fetch row `$_GET['id']` of your SQL query:

```
$call = pg_query("SELECT AlternativeSolusi FROM Call WHERE CallID = ".intval($_GET['id']);
$result=pg_fetch_row($call);
echo $result[0];
```

Some further basic reading for you:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
- http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: which PHP code do you mean? I have attached it all. Does $_get need a <form> tag? I used $result[1] as unique data because it's a code at my database.

Comment: @Shieryn I modified your code and added additional guidance. Please let me know if that makes sense. I *strongly* recommend adding an `id` column to your database.

Comment: I already have that id column. The name is CallID. I already tried as you said. But at the popup link didn't change and $get['index'] didn't work.

Comment: @Shieryn Let me edit my code using the `CallID` as the unique ID... done. Please clarify what you mean by, "the popup link didn't change"?

Answer (score 2):

Using sesions or wuery string will be helpful to pass data on external page.
so for rexample
you redirect to external page with query string like
www.ewxample.in?q=yourdata

on receiver side read the same data with the help of php like

```
<?php
   echo $_GET["q"];  //Output: youdata
?>
```